# A question related to the support of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am currently working on the following question:

> Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ and consider the ideal $I=(X^2 YZ,Z^2 )\subset R$. Find the support and associated primes of $R/I$ and give a minimal primary decomposition of $I.$

Here is my progress so far (feel free to point out any mistakes): $(1)$ $I=(Z)\cap(Z^2,X^2)\cap (Y,Z^2)$ is a minimal primary decomposition of $I$ with associated primes $(Z), (Z,X),(Z,Y)$,
$(2)$ Primary decomposition of $R/I=(Z)/I \cap (X^2 Z,X^4 )/I \cap (YZ,Y^4 )/I$ with associated primes $(Z),(Z,X),(Z,Y).$

But I am not entirely sure how to compute the support of $R/I.$ Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (2) is not correct. The primary decomposition you mentioned is not for $R/I$, is for the zero ideal in $R/I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{Supp}(R/I)=V(I)$, that is, the set of all prime ideals containing $I$. Such a prime ideal contains $(Z)$ (and vice versa), so the support is the set of all prime ideals of $R$ which contain $(Z)$.